# How to run implicit broadcast in Android Oreo?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-8.0-oreo

I have read the other solutions, but I am creating the new question because of the broadcast limit in the Android O.

My app is working on the broadcast of Google Play Music app. When the user play the music it will save the music's data. Declaration of the receiver in manifest file is as below:

```
    <receiver
        android:name=".syncMusic.stock.StockMusicReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true"
        tools:ignore="ExportedReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.music.playstatechanged"/>
            <action android:name="com.android.music.metachanged"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

It works perfect before Version O. I have read the [Background Execution limits in O](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html#broadcasts).

> By default, these changes only affect apps that target Android 8.0 (API level 26) or higher. However, users can enable these restrictions for any app from the Settings screen, even if the app targets an API level lower than 26. You may need to update your app to comply with the new limitations.

**How can I use Job scheduler to run play music's broadcast in Android O (like the previous versions of Android) when app is not running in background?**

Comment: Same issue here I have a BootupReceiver for me to start FCM services,  this probably won't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can register your broadcast receiver programmatically.

**Hint**: Use getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(...) if you do it from within a BroadcastReceiver class, Android will throw an Exception otherwise (not allowed from within a BroadcastReceiver context)